# Orient SQL find shortestPath using specific list of classes

Tags: orientdb

I want to find the shortest path using Orient SQL between two nodes where edge type is type_A or type_B but not type_C.

From the documentation (http://orientdb.com/docs/master/SQL-Functions.html#shortestpath) it looks like only one edge type is supported. Is it possible to mention a list of edge types? Or is there any other way to find it?

Comment: Hi, can you add more information?

Comment: Reading the documentation I don't think you can do it. Could a javascript function be usefull to you ?

Comment: More info about the use case:

Comment: More info about the use case:

I have a people's graph. A person can be connected to another person by different ways (edges) such as works together, went to same school, friends, family etc. Based on context, the relation type in find shortest path changes. Normally its just one type but there are cases where I need to fetch by multiple types.

Comment: @AlessandroRota, its a java application. Thanks for the help.